# Total Count in AWS CloudWatch Metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I'm looking for a way in AWS CloudWatch Metrics for AWS SES to get the total number of emails sent in a specified time. Currently I can only get count as a specific time data points which means I need to calculate each data points and then get the total number of emails sent in say last 24 hours.

I'm sure there would be a way in CloudWatch by using math to it but could it.

Anyone aware of such way?

Thanks,
Imran

Comment: Have you attempted any CloudWatch queries so far? This will help me understand where the issue lies.